# FusionTablesLayer not working with google maps version 3.22/3.23

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

we have a problem with our fusion table implementation when using google maps versin 3.23 (exp) or 3.22 (stable). With these versions, when we are trying to create a layer, we get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of undefined. The following lines in our code is not working with 3.23 or 3.22:

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            query: {
                select: 'Full address',
                from: selectedFusionTableId,
                where: sql
            },
            options: { suppressInfoWindows: true },
            styleId: 1,
            templateId: selectedFusionTableInfoWindowTemplateId
        });
```

The implementation has been working with google maps version 3.21 (current frozen version) for a year, so I wonder if there are something we can do on our side or if there is something broken in the google maps versions 3.22 and 3.23?

Since google maps is using version rollover, our implementation will stop working next time google updates googlemaps versions.

Application can be found here:
http://studera.nu/studera-utomlands/utbytesprogram/erasmus/

/Magnus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problm was finally found in our code and it was caused by a global js function called Error(). Changing the name on the function to a more specific name resolved the issue and our application started to work against google maps version 3.22 and 3.23. Our guess is that Error() function conflicted with a function with the same name in google maps js file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce the problem from a simple embedded map using "Tools > Publish" and changing the Maps API version. I suspect there's something going on with your app that is different from that code; can you reproduce using the generated Fusion Tables publish HTML?

BTW, the code above works, but it would be cleaner to use options for style and template IDs, e.g.,

```
options: {
 suppressInfoWindows: true,
 styleId: 1,
 templateId: selectedFusionTableInfoWindowTemplateId
}
```